# Adob Air RTMP Player

Tags: android, flash, air, adobe, rtmp

I'm developing application for Android. It's a player that have to play RTMP protocol video. 
I have read that it is necessary to have Flash Player installed which is deprecated for Android. But there is also Adobe Air technology, that is also from Adobe. I'm interested if it's possible to play RTMP video with Adobe Air technology ? Or I will anyway have to install Flash Player ?

Comment: Erik.Martirosyan if u did this tell me how ? i have same task to achive . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Feel free to use your AS3 code for Android AIR development, it'll work fine with RTMP streams.

Comment: can you provide some refrence link to achive following task i also need to do.  Thanks

Comment: the task was cancelled, so I haven't implemented this feature.